# How to write if contition in visual force..?

Tags: visualforce

Follow-up action : 
   1. (matter goes here Followup1)   Assigned to :  (new field AssignedTo1)  Due Date : (New field DueDate1) Priority : (new Field Priority1)
   2. (matter goes here Followup2)  Assigned to : (new field AssignedTo2)  Due Date : (new field DueDate2) Priority : (New field Priority2)

like wise

if the followup  is not null then only we have to populate that particular row
Say only 2 followups are there, the 3,4,5 rows need not be displayed

in visual force...

Can any one help me how to check that condition..

The following is the code i wrote..

**1.**

```
  <td><b>Assigned to:</b><apex:outputField value="{!FieldVisitReport__c.AssignedTo1__c}" /></td>
  <td ><b>Due Date :</b><apex:outputField value="{!FieldVisitReport__c.DueDate1__c}" /></td>

  <td><b>Priority : </b><apex:outputField value="{!FieldVisitReport__c.Priority1__c}" /></td>
  </tr>

       <tr>
```

**2.**

```
  <td><b>Assigned to:</b><apex:outputField value="{!FieldVisitReport__c.AssignedTo1__c}" /></td>
  <td ><b>Due Date :</b><apex:outputField value="{!FieldVisitReport__c.DueDate1__c}" /></td>

  <td><b>Priority : </b><apex:outputField value="{!FieldVisitReport__c.Priority1__c}" /></td>
  </tr>


  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <tr>
```

**iii.**

```
  <td><b>Assigned to:</b><apex:outputField value="{!FieldVisitReport__c.AssignedTo3__c}" /></td>
  <td ><b>Due Date :</b><apex:outputField value="{!FieldVisitReport__c.DueDate3__c}" /></td>

  <td><b>Priority : </b><apex:outputField value="{!FieldVisitReport__c.Priority3__c}" /></td>
  </tr>
   </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{(!FieldVisitReport__c.FollowupAction4__c)!=null }">

     <tr>
```